# Question about the proof that a countable union of countable sets is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

## Can One explain me a bit about  the `Hence`

---

> 2.12 Theorem

Let $\{E_n\}$, where $n=1,2,3,...$, be a sequence of countable sets, and put

$S=\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\cup }}E_n$.

Then $S$ is countable.

#### Proof

---

Let every set $E_n$ be arranged in a sequence $\left\{x_{\text{nk}}\right\},k=1,2,3,\text{...},$

and consider the infinite array

(16) [image: images]

in which the elements of $E_n$ form the nth row.

The array contains all elements of $S$. As indicated by the arrows, these elements can be arranged in a sequence

(17) $x_{11};x_{21},x_{12};x_{31},x_{22},x_{13};x_{41},x_{32},x_{23},x_{14};\text{...}$

**Sentence 1** If any two of the sets $E_n$ have elements in common, these will appear more than once in (17).

**Sentence 2** Hence there is a subset $T$ of the set of all positive integers such that $S\sim T$, which shows that $S$ is at most countable. Since $E_1\subset S$, and $E_1$ is infinite, $S$ is infinite, and thus countable.

**Problem**:
What's the relation between sentence 1 and sentence 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could have been stated a bit more clearly; let me expand it a bit. $(17)$ is to be understood as exhibiting this correspondence with the set of positive integers:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
\Bbb Z^+:&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&\ldots\\
S:&x_{11}&x_{21}&x_{12}&x_{31}&x_{22}&x_{13}&x_{41}&x_{32}&x_{23}&x_{14}&x_{51}&\ldots
\end{array}$$

The problem is that some of the entries in the $S$ row may be identical; e.g., it might be that $x_{12}=x_{23}$ and $x_{11}=x_{22}=x_{32}$. In that case the correspondence isn’t a bijection between $\Bbb Z^+$ and $S$. However, we can strike out any duplicates in the bottom line, leaving something like this, for instance:

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
T:&1&2&3&4&\bullet&6&7&\bullet&\bullet&10&11&\ldots\\
S:&x_{11}&x_{21}&x_{12}&x_{31}&\bullet&x_{13}&x_{41}&\bullet&\bullet&x_{14}&x_{51}&\ldots
\end{array}$$

(I’ve replaced the deleted items with bullets for greater visual clarity; in fact the deleted items are simply gone.) We now have a bijection between the two sets that remain. On the bottom line we still have the set $S$, since we struck out only extra copies. On the top line we have some subset $T$ of $\Bbb Z^+$.

The *Hence* in Sentence $2$ actually refers to the fact that although we may not have a bijection of $S$ with $\Bbb Z^+$, we do have one with a subset $T$ of $\Bbb Z^+$. It’s the existence of $T$ and the fact that it may only be a subset of $\Bbb Z^+$ that follow from the previous sentence, as indicated by *hence*.

Answer (score 3):

When we want to prove a set is countable, we produce an **injection** from said set to $\Bbb N$. Since elements may repeat in $(17)$, the author wants to avoid this to make the map actually an injection. Since here it seems countable stands for "countably infinite", the construction produces a bijection: we already have surjection since we know the sets are countably infinite to begin with, the deletion of repeated entries produces the desired bijection.

Comment: Hi，I've understood the answers given by them. I have questions in your termilogy about injection which I am not so familiar with.`When we prove a set is countable, we produce an *injection* between from said set to N`. not a `bijection`-one-one mapping? and In your last line, you used the `desired bijection`, I understand this.

Comment: @HyperGroups When I said "countable" what I mean, maybe in your terminology, is "at most countable"; that is $|A|\leq |\Bbb N|$ (which is exactly the assertion that there exists an injection $A\to \Bbb N$). But it seems you use "finite" for $|A|<|\Bbb N|$ and "countable" exclusively for $|A|=|\Bbb N|$ which is why I changed and used "countably infinite" to convey this.

Comment: ah, got it. Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

(17) is giving a sequence in $S$ such that every element of $S$ appears at least once as a term of the sequence.  This may be viewed as a surjective function $f: \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow S$.  To get a bijection, starting from $1$ and working upwards we can simply remove from the domain every positive integer $n$ such that $f(n) = f(m)$ for some $m < n$.  This gives a bijection: $f: T \subset \mathbb{Z}^+ \rightarrow S$.