# How to understand the words "More algebraically"

Tags: education

#### How to understand the words `More algebraically`

---

When seeing one proof about the theorem that rational set is countable, I saw this

> **More algebraically** , but less clearly, an explicit one-to-one onto map

$f:N\times N\to N$

is

$f(m,n)=\frac{(n+m-2)(n+m-1)}{2}+m$.

so, why not more analytically? The concept of function is more algebraically?

Also, better to know about how to construct $f(m,n)$ and make it more clearly?

Comment: The function is a **polynomial**. Can't really get more algebraic than that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help to know what is being contrasted with this more algebraic argument. I suspect, however, that it’s a pictorial argument similar to the one shown in [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438597/question-about-the-proof-that-a-countable-union-of-countable-sets-is-countable). If so, the author’s point is that while the picture makes it very clear that there **is** a bijection $f$ from $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ and would even let us calculate any $f(m,n)$ by drawing a big enough picture, it doesn’t actually give us an algebraic formula for $f(m,n)$.

Now he’s giving us that algebraic formula. It’s not terribly hard to prove that it’s a formula for the bijection of the pictorial argument. It’s also not hard to prove **without** any reference to the pictorial argument that this function really is a bijection from $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$. But it would be hard to come up with that formula out of thin air. If he had just presented the formula and proved that it’s a bijection from $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$, you might well have said, ‘Fine, I see that it works, but where on earth did it *come* from?!’

It’s more algebraic because it actually gives an algebraic expression for $f$; it’s less clear because you actually have to work a bit to prove that it’s a bijection from $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$; the pictorial argument gives you an obvious bijection, even though it isn’t immediately obvious how to express it with an algebraic formula.

Comment: ah, yes, there is really one picture show the diagonalization. 

---"Fine, I see that it works, but where on earth did it come from?!"

Comment: @HyperGroups: You might not come up with the idea of counting off by diagonals, at least not right away, but I think that it’s still a good deal less mysterious than the formula. (Of course I first saw the idea about $55$ years ago, so I may not be the best judge of how natural it is!)

Comment: Is there a gold badge here for "consistently quite outstandingly clear explanations -- models of how to do it"? Then @BrianM.Scott should get a handful! :-)

Answer (score 1):

One interpretation would be that they've provided an algebraic formula (i.e. an explicit formula involving only multiplication, division, etc) for the mapping in question, instead of simply *proving* that the mapping exists.  One might say that proving something exists without explicitly constructing it, such as in the proof of counting the rationals, is a more "analytical" thing to do, since we're simply analyzing the problem instead of getting caught up in the symbols (the algebra) of it.

Comment: en, maybe is one reason that the formula is algebraically.