# A countable product of topological spaces each of which has a countable basis

Tags: general-topology

Does a countable product of topological spaces each of which has a countable basis have a countable basis?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Let $X=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\mathscr{B}_n$ be a countable base for $X_n$. For each finite $F\subseteq\Bbb N$ let

$$\mathscr{B}_F=\left\{\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n:U_n\in\mathscr{B}_n\text{ if }n\in F\text{ and }U_n=X_n\text{ otherwise}\right\}\;;$$

$\mathscr{B}_F$ is countable. Let

$$\mathscr{B}=\bigcup\{\mathscr{B}_F:F\subseteq\Bbb N\text{ is finite}\}\;;$$

$\mathscr{B}$ is the union of countably many countable sets and is a base for $X$.

Comment: @William: There’s an obvious bijection between $\mathscr{B}_F$ and $\prod_{n\in F}\mathscr{B}_n$. The latter is the product of finitely many countable sets and therefore is countable.

Comment: How do you prove that the set of finite subsets of the set of natural numbers is countable?

Comment: @William: For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\mathscr{F}_n$ be the family of $n$-element subsets of $\Bbb N$; clearly every finite subset of $\Bbb N$ is in one of the $\mathscr{F}_n$, and there are only countably many of them, so it suffices to see that each $\mathscr{F}_n$ is countable. For each $n$ there is an easy injection from $\mathscr{F}_n$ into $\Bbb N^n$; the latter, as the product of finitely many countable sets, is countable, so $\mathscr{F}_n$ is countable as well.

Comment: How do you prove that a countable union of countable sets is countable?

Comment: @William: You’ll find proofs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/55188/12042), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1074610/12042), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438597/question-about-the-proof-that-a-countable-union-of-countable-sets-is-countable).

Comment: So we need the axiom choice to prove that the question is affirmative.
Right?

Comment: @William: Only the weaker [axiom of countable choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice), and no choice at all if each of the spaces comes equipped with a *counted* base, i.e., one with a specified indexing by $\Bbb N$ or a subset thereof. (It’s not really something to worry about, considering that one of the most important and useful theorems in topology is actually equivalent to $\mathsf{AC}$.)

Comment: "*one of the most important and useful theorems in topology is actually equivalent to AC.*" What is it?

Comment: @William: The Tikhonov product theorem, that says that an arbitrary product of compact spaces is compact.

Comment: We can prove that a coutable product of metric compact spaces is compact without AC. No?

Comment: @William: What do you mean by *usual*?

Comment: Metric compact spaces

Comment: @William: No: it requires some choice just to prove that all products of countably infinitely many finite discrete spaces are compact.

Comment: That's interesting. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @William: [This PDF](www.math.ucla.edu/~znorwood/files/tychonoffimpliesac.pdf) has the standard proof that the full Tikhonov theorem implies $\mathsf{AC}$. You can easily adapt it to show that if countable products of finite discrete spaces are compact, then arbitrary products $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$ of non-empty finite sets $X_n$ are non-empty, i.e., the axiom of choice for countable families of finite sets. This is known to be independent of $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: In most pracatical examples, a countable product of metric compact spaces can be trivially proved to be non-empty without AC.
For example, the countable product of the interval $[0, 1]$.

Comment: @William: Speaking as a set-theoretic topologist, I really have no idea what you mean by *practical*: that’s not a distinction that I make.

Comment: I mean a case in which a countable family of compact metric spaces is given *concretely* or *constructibly*.

Comment: @William: That’s simply not a distinction that I find useful or very interesting.